# How to put total size and usage of the dropbox in label in iOS

Tags: dropbox, space, dropbox-api, quota

I need to display total size of the dropbox using Quota space in label. Any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios) you can use these methods to get the account information, which includes quota information:

- (void)loadAccountInfo;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedAccountInfo:(DBAccountInfo*)info;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadAccountInfoFailedWithError:(NSError*)error;

This is unfortunately not currently exposed in the [Sync SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios) though.

Comment: I put like this but it doesn't work.                                                                      -(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedAccountInfo:(DBAccountInfo *)info
{
      NSLog(@"load account info");
      long spacecConsumed=info.quota.totalBytes;
      long totalSpace=info.quota.totalConsumedBytes;
       NSLog(@"spaceConsumed %ld",spacecConsumed);
       NSLog(@"total space %ld",totalSpace);
}

Comment: It displays space consume = 0 and total space is also 0

Comment: That code actually works fine for me. Are you sure you are linked to an active account when running that?

Comment: I Put this code in Dropboxviewcontroller.m.And I am using CORE API. Just to see it is work or not but it doesn't display  space and total.